# CKEDITOR It does not work on Server Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can not find a solution to this dilemma that looks tired I did not find a solution where it's running on the local server and do not work on the server hosting where you wonder if the problem did not work all the obligations in your opinion what is the solution!

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name)

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['Name'];
    if (editor) { editor.instances(true); }
    CKEDITOR.replace('Name', {
        enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
    });


    </script>

}
```

in Web.config

```
  <add key="CKEDITOR_BASEPATH" value="/Scripts/ckeditor/"/>
```

Comment: Do you see an error message in the javascript console?

Comment: <script src="/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

Comment: And you are sure the file is on the server?

Comment: Of course sure the file is on the server

Comment: Well, if you get a 404 your paths are not correct somewhere. So you'll need to double check them, that the rendered path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And finally reached a solution

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name)
<script src="http://Domain/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['QustionName'];
    if (editor) { editor.instances(true); }
    CKEDITOR.replace('QustionName', {
        enterMode: CKEDITOR.basePath,
    });

    </script>
```

in Web.config

```
<add key="CKEDITOR_BASEPATH" value="/Scripts/ckeditor/"/>
```

What I did was that

1. I went to NuGet-Package-manager and ckeditor-basic.
2. and go to http://ckeditor.com/download And I built the appropriate
   additions.
3. Raise your chosen additions in hosting a folder in a special folder.
4. Add Scripts precedes all lead to file appropriate
   additions ckeditor.js.

And Run Everything became okay.

```
<script src="http://Domain/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```